# Display 'same level' categories in Opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Here are the changes applied according to @daniel's Answer.

In \catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\sibling_category.tpl

```
          <div class="box box-with-categories">
              <div class="box-heading check_2"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
              <div class="strip-line"></div>
              <div class="box-content box-category">
                <ul class="accordion" id="accordion-category">
                  <?php $i = 0; foreach ($categories as $category) { $i++; ?>
                  <li class="panel">
                    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </li>
                  <?php } ?>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
```

\catalog\controller\extension\module\sibling_category.php

```
  <!--Have changed the controller logic, like you said -->
```

And In \catalog\language\en-gb\extension\module\sibling_category.php

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title'] = 'Sibling Categories';
```

So, Now what to do for appearing on list -> inside Category Layout.
And is there any way we can do this in coding so this appear in product/category.tpl file, so we don't need to create all files in admin folder.

Comment: Please add more context or describe your problem more generally. We don't know why Pizza and Pasta are categories, and we don't know what you've tried to do.

Comment: @schuelermine Please have a Look.

Comment: Hey @schuelermine let me know if its still confusing for you.

Comment: @Anmol_singh I don't know. I'm not familiar with opencart

Comment: @Anmolsingh so you're trying to get the same menu items that were displayed on the previous page? e.g. while in Pizza, you want to see all the other sibling items in Pizza's parent category

Comment: No @Daniel. I want to see the other siblings of Pizza's Category. So, i have Pasta, Drinks, Deseret on Pizza's category page.

Comment: I hope this simple thing is possible. @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've rewritten this answer to make it simpler to follow.

Your best bet here is to create a new Module rather than including this in the template. There are two stages: creating admin files & creating front-end files.

**FRONT END**

Start by duplicating all the front-end files of the standard "Category" module which consist of the following files, rename them according to your own definition e.g. `sibling_category` wherever you have `category`:

```
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\category.tpl
\catalog\controller\extension\module\category.php
\catalog\language\en-gb\extension\module\category.php
```

We don't need a model here as the model for this as the `ModelCatalogCategory` class has the desired ability already.

So now you need to change the controller logic, edit the newly created `sibling_category.php` controller file. What we're doing here is getting the current category data (`$current_id` & `$current_category`), extracting the Parent category's id (`parent_id`) and then getting all children of the `parent_id` aka "siblings"

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleSiblingCategory extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/category');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $current_id = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

        $current_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($current_id);

        $siblings = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($current_category['parent_id']);

        foreach ($siblings as $category) {

            $data['sibling_categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category['name'] ,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }

        $data['current_id'] = $current_id;

        return $this->load->view('extension/module/sibling_category', $data);
    }
}
```

Here's the default OC template's category.tpl modules file adjusted (edit for your template file accordingly replacing "$category_id" with "$current_id":

```
<div class="list-group">
  <?php foreach ($sibling_categories as $category) { ?>
  <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $current_id) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
  <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
  <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item active">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**ADMIN AREA**
In order to manage the module in the admin area, you will need to duplicate the language file and create a controller and the view:

```
\admin\language\en-gb\extension\module\category.php
```

Create a new file in the path `\admin\controller\extension\module\sibling_category.php` and insert this code:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleSiblingCategory extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/sibling_category');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('extension/module');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
                $this->model_extension_module->addModule('sibling_category', $this->request->post);
            } else {
                $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
            }

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true));
        }

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

        $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

        $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true)
        );

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/html', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
            );
        } else {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/html', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true)
            );
        }

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/sibling_category', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);
        } else {
            $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/sibling_category', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true);
        }

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true);

        if (isset($this->request->get['module_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
            $module_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
            $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
        } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
            $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
        } else {
            $data['name'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['module_description'])) {
            $data['module_description'] = $this->request->post['module_description'];
        } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
            $data['module_description'] = $module_info['module_description'];
        } else {
            $data['module_description'] = array();
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/language');

        $data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

        if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
            $data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
        } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
            $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
        } else {
            $data['status'] = '';
        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/sibling_category', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/category')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Finally create the view file at the path `\admin\view\template\extension\module\sibling_category.tpl` and insert the following:

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-category" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-html" class="form-horizontal">        
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <select name="status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Once you've done this, you may need to update your admin permissions. Navigate to "Settings=>Users=>UserGroups" and edit your Admin user type. Make sure you either "Select All" for read and modify permission or select it manually.

You need to then "Install" this module and then edit it, set it to enabled and Save. You'll notice a "Sub-module" listed below the "Sibling Category" this is to get the module in the 'Layouts' page. Do not create multiple instances of the module as it may cause confusion on the layouts - unless you understand what you're doing.

**NB When duplicating the language files, remember to find & replace all instances of "Category" with "Sibling Category"**

Comment: Thank you @daniel, i am applying the changes. And will let you know if stuck somewhere.

Comment: Hi @daniel, I have edited the question acc to your answer. Have a Look.

Comment: @Anmolsingh I'm not sure what you need now, please be specific

Comment: OK "Daniel. I mean i have applied all the changes(of frontend) that you mentioned. So, what to do next? So, i can select this module to appear on category page. -- When i go to admin->Layout->Category. there is no option to select this Sibling_category Module. Mean now we need to figure out Back-end changes as you said before.

Comment: @Anmolsingh sorry, I completely overlooked that part. I've updated the answer

Comment: I have applied your changes, Now when i go to Admin Panel-> Extensions->Module, here i can select this module Enable/Disable. But still can not see the listing in Admin Panel->Layout->Category. ALSO, you mentioned in Admin part to add this *CODE in \admin\language\en-gb\extension\module\sibling_category.php   i think you mean to say to add this code in controller file rather than in language? (I tried this way).

Comment: @Anmolsingh thanks for the feedback, it's entirely possible I've missed a step. I'll look into this over the weekend and see why it's not working

Comment: Hi @Daniel. waiting for your Answer.

Comment: @Anmolsingh unfortunately, setting up a test environment to assist you to troubleshoot this further is low priority at the moment. If you're in a rush, use the code samples I've provided and overwrite the default category controller / views but this may break other things

Comment: @Anmolsingh I've improved on the previous answer